# Have to hook into a function from a module

Tags: 7, hooks

I am using the [LinkedIn Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkedin) module and have created a custom module to add some functionality.

Please see the linkedin.inc file at line 17 - function linkedin_access_token($account)

When a user links their LinkedIn account, I want to add to the db_write_record to also write to a custom field in my database for a timestamp.

Not sure what hook to use since it is a function.

Answer (score 1):

Just making a quickly research (I don't have time at this moment to test the code) inside the [Linkedin Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkedin) module I can tell you that I found a hook named `linkedin_external_login`

See the code in the linkedin_auth/linkedin_auth.module file in the line 124

```
/*
 * Implementation of hook_linkedin_external_login
 */

function linkedin_auth_linkedin_external_login($uid) {
  $name = db_query("SELECT authname FROM {authmap} WHERE uid = :uid AND module = :module", array(':uid' => $uid, ':module' => 'linkedin'))->fetchField();
  user_external_login_register($name, 'linkedin');
  drupal_goto();
}
```

Just implement your own `hook_linkedin_external_login()`

Comment: Hello. Thank you for this information. I am actually using CAS login with LinkedIn Integration (not using LinkedIn for login) to display in profiles only.

Comment: linkedin_profile is the module I am using.